# Android - is there any way to change WiFi signal to 5GHz?

Tags: android, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

My problem is first: when I use WiFi and Bluetooth at the same time then my WiFi becomes "unstable" and my WiFi just drops down. The basic problem is here: the WiFi and the BT use the same frequency, 2.4 GHz.

Is there any way to fix that, or any way to change my WiFi to use 5GHz signal?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with changing wifi to 5Ghz? If your hardware supports the 802.11a or 802.11n standard you can use of course a channel in the 5Ghz range. However you know that you have to configure the WLan settings on your access point?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AP that has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz and both are set with the same SSID, I'm not sure you can specify to use one over the other (at least, I can't seem to on my phone).  Sometimes you can specify different SSID's for the different radios so it looks like 2 access points and then you can specifically connect to just the 5GHz one.  I know you can do this with OpenWRT, but a lot of stock router firmwares may not allow this.

You should be able to do BT and Wifi at the same time even if they're both at 2.4GHz provided the hardware/software has the proper set up to co-exist.  I have used some cheaper hardware that despite having drivers to help the two co-exist, they don't seem to be able to both work at the same time (one usually gets cut off).

I'm not sure if you can get different connection managers for Android, but if you could find one where you can specify a BSSID then you could specify to connect to only the 5GHz radio on your router.